# Laravel: belongsTo method issue

Tags: laravel, relationship, belongs-to

I have models called "Designations" and "TeamMembers". I am connecting them with 'Model Relationships' in a Laravel(v5.8.4) application. Also these tables are connected via Primary Key and Foreign Key constraints in the database.

Error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: F:\Files\Programming\Web\PHP\wamp\www\Php\Projects\MUC028-CodeLiver128\Laravel\resources\views\administrator\team-members\elements\_grid.blade.php)"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in F:\Files\Programming\Web\PHP\wamp\www\Php\Projects\MUC028-CodeLiver128\Laravel\storage\framework\views\be1013e7ebf4b2a7b40bda946160daf4cc4fe012.php:0
```

Models:

```
class Designations extends Model
{
    /**
     * Relationships
     */
    public function teamMembers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TeamMembers::class);
    }

    ...
}

class TeamMembers extends Model
{
    /**
     * Relationships
     */
    public function designation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Designations::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

Tables:

```
Designations:
    id
    title
    ...

TeamMembers:
    id
    designations_id
    full_name
    ...
```

View:

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {!! $value->designation->title !!}
@endforeach
```

I tried using model names(`Designations`) instead of class `Designations::class` but its not working. I am always getting the same error.

Comment: What piece of code that causes this error?

Comment: Try swapping out TeamMembers::class and Designations::class for 'App\TeamMembers' and 'App\Desgnations'

Comment: I have updated the question, added the view code which is generating the issue.

Comment: @JamieBurton i tried your answer but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you can try hasMany('App\TeamMembers', 'team_member_id_column') and the inverse for Destinations?

Comment: try to `dd()` your data from the view to see what is being returned to the view. Might help you find your issue.

Comment: @JamieBurton i tried but still nothing. @TJWeems ```dd()``` only returns ```null```